Application Properties in Spring Boot do not appear to be defined in the codebase and are coming from an outside source
I have recently taken over a spring boot application.
In the resources directory there an application.yml and a datasource.properties file.
I have come across an issue where in a class file the code has a property defined in this manner
@Value("${fax-service.password}")
private String faxPassword;

In my application.yml file there is a section that defines attribute for this.
fax-service:
   userid:"somevalue"
   url: "http://someurl"

But the password is not defined here. I have added debug/info loggers to see what password is being used during runtime and even though I added an attribute for that section it keeps using a different value.  It is the same value consistently regardless of what I define in the .yml file and section.
I have searched the server for any additional .yml or .properties files.  I have gone to the system environment variables and found nothing defined there:

I have looked in the tomcat directory and I do not see any setEnv.sh files and there is nothing in any of the .bat or .sh files related to JAVA_OPTS in any of those files. There are also no argument variables being passed to tomcat when it starts.
I know that I can use the @PropertySource() annotation to more or less force the application to use the application.yml file.
However, there are multiple values that are pulling from this mystery source, and I would like to be able to know where they are coming from since the previous developers thought that obscuring them would add an extra layer of security since some of the values are sensitive data. Therefore I would like to keep that in place, but be able to modify the values in the event that I have to change them in the future. The previous development group is now defunct and no longer reachable.

Without knowing what you are using for dependencies and other structures this is impossible to answer. Check the spring boot documentation for all the sources that are consulted, if you enabled debug/trace logging you will get quite extensive information what values are retrieved from where, so determing which value is actually being used should be pretty easy.

Does your app by any chance use spring-cloud? If yes, there could be an external property source configured.

I don't see any references to spring-cloud in my dependency list in the pom.xml and searching the codebase does not return any hits on the term 'cloud'.  Should I look somewhere else for that?

If you haven't seen https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.M1/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html, it might help you to narrow it down.  This is everywhere external that Spring will look for properties.

Do the project use spring-cloud-config? You may never notice references from the source.

After looking in a lot of places, I was able to locate the properties that were not defined in the application.yml.
At M. Deinum's proding, I increased the level of logging to TRACE to see if it showed my anything that I may have missed.  It was a lot of information, but not exactly what I was looking for.  However, I did find in one of the catalina log files that on Tomcat startup it was declaring a lot of commandline arguments.
When I looked at the windows service that was created the only commandline argument I could see was //RS. Looking further into Tomcat as a Windows service I came across
How to pass a parameter to a windows service once and for all at install instead of each start
This lead me to look in the registry editor for the windows service ImagePath for the commandline argumets.  Again, there was nothing there.
Finally I came across this post
Passing JVM arguments to Tomcat when running as a service?
Here is lead me to the Tomcat Administrator Application found in Tomcat/bin directory.  Running that and switching to the JAVA tab is where all the commandline arguments were found.

Here I was able to modify the ones that I needed to adjust, restart the tomcat service and problem solved.
